# Replacing alpha inside rgba issue

Tags: javascript, css, background-color, alpha

I did the following function to replace the alpha inside an rgba string:

```
function replaceAlpha(elemAttr,alpha) {
    elemAttr = elemAttr.replace(elemAttr.substring(elemAttr.lastIndexOf(",")+1,elemAttr.lastIndexOf(")")),alpha)
}
```

but it doesn't seem to work even if the result is correct see:

```js
function replaceAlpha(elemAttr,alpha) {
    elemAttr = elemAttr.replace(elemAttr.substring(elemAttr.lastIndexOf(",")+1,elemAttr.lastIndexOf(")")),alpha)
    console.log(elemAttr)
}
replaceAlpha(document.getElementById("invisibleSpan").style.backgroundColor,0)
```

```html
<span id="invisibleSpan" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);color:white">I wanna be invisible</span>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: you are not setting the style to your element, only computing the new color

Comment: how would i set the style to my element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What your issue here is thinking that the style would update directly from the function. You are simply generating the new style but not updating the background color itself. Here's an updated version of your code:

I simply returned your new value from your function and set it as the new background color.

```
function replaceAlpha(elemAttr,alpha) {
    return elemAttr.replace(elemAttr.substring(elemAttr.lastIndexOf(",")+1,elemAttr.lastIndexOf(")")),alpha)
}

const elem = document.getElementById("invisibleSpan")
const rgba = replaceAlpha(elem.style.backgroundColor,0);
elem.style.backgroundColor = rgba;
```

If you want to update it from the function, you can do this instead:

```
function replaceAlpha(element,alpha) {
    const backgroundColor = element.style.backgroundColor;
    const [r,g,b,a] = backgroundColor.split(',');
    const newBackgroundColor = [r,g,b,alpha].join(',') + ')';

    element.style.backgroundColor = newBackgroundColor;
}

const elem = document.getElementById("invisibleSpan")
replaceAlpha(elem, 0);
```

Added a way to update from the function itself with any element and color attribute. Note that this doesn't handle validations. You can encounter errors if you don't check whether the property you are replacing is actually a color, I'll leave that task to you:

```
function replaceAlpha(element, attribute, alpha) {
    const color = element.style[attribute];
    const [r,g,b,a] = color.split(',');
    const newColor = [r,g,b,alpha].join(',') + ')';

    element.style[attribute] = newColor;
}

const elem = document.getElementById("invisibleSpan")
replaceAlpha(elem, 'backgroundColor',0);
```

Comment: thank you, is there a way to change the style inside the function?

Comment: Hi @wooldLucky, updated it, hope that helps. I changed the approach for changing the value, so it's a bit more cleaner. Could still be cleaner, but only to show a quick sample.

Comment: thanks but i'd like to be able to do that not only with the background color but maybe with the color or any other color attributes

Comment: Yes, you can do that by passing both the `element` and the `color attribute` you want to change. You can actually do something like this `element.style['backgroundColor'] = newColor`. Not advisable, but possible. Also note that you can encounter a lot of problems doing this way if you are not validating inputs properly. Updated above to include the sample.